# regex to match substring exist in javascript

Tags: javascript, regex, url

I want to write a regex to match whether my url has gmt.php or not. For example:

If my url is `http://example.com/gmt.php?a=1` it is true

If my url is `http://example.com/ac.php` then it is false

I tried:

```
/^([a-z0-9])$/.test('gmt.php');
```

but its not perfect. And yes I need only regex not substring match `indexOf`
Thanks.

Comment: *"but its not perfect"* - or in any way related to what you're trying to do... May I suggest that you google up a regex tutorial, and you'll find this is very easy to implement.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Why not simply indexOf

```
url.indexOf( "gmt.php" ) != -1 //outputs true if it exists
```

For regex (not sure why you want regex for such simple thing ;))

```
/gmt\.php/.test('http://example.com/gmt.php?a=1 ');
```

or

```
/gmt.php/.test('http://example.com/gmt.php?a=1 ');//since . is . outside []
```

> /^([a-z0-9])$/.test('gmt.php');
>
> but its not perfect.

Because `/^([a-z0-9])$/` will only match **one alpha-numeric character**.

Comment: it is not regex, I need regex. :)

Comment: Thanks but I need it because some regex was already written for it and I have to use in that flow :)

Comment: @BhuvneshGupta did you tried the regex I have shared?

Comment: This is working fine but I need some more correction. It should match if there is anything before or after gmt.php e.g if it is abgmt.phpa then it should also return true.

Answer (score 0):

Try this instead: /gmt.php/.test(url)

```
<html>
<head><title>foo</title>
<script>
function foo(url) {
  alert(/gmt.php/.test(url));
}
</script>
</head>
<body>
<form>
<input type="text" id="text" size="40"><input type="button" onclick="foo(document.getElementById('text').value)">
</form>
</body>
```

Answer (score 0):

```js
var reg = /^(?:https?:\/\/\w+\.\w+\/)?\w+\.\w+\?\w+\=\w+$/;
var url1 = 'http://example.com/gmt.php?a=1';
var url2 = 'http://example.com/ac.php';
var url3 = 'gmt.php?a=1';
var url4 = 'gmt.php'
    console.log(reg.test(url1));
    console.log(reg.test(url2));
    console.log(reg.test(url3));
    console.log(reg.test(url4));
```

if have other fail data,please @me,